# When is the right time to use an application server?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rmi, application-server

Throughout development I've separated my code into standalone projects, most of which receive a JMS feed, do some processing on each message, persist the domain object and then services are exposed for some of the other projects to call using RMI. All of them, apart from the web app run (which runs on tomcat), of which there are now 6, run as standalone jars. I guess this can be inferred from the above but I don't use EJBs; all of the projects use Spring.

I've got very limited experience using tomcat and almost no experience of using application servers but it occurred to me today that these apps could be hosted on either tomcat/app server and I feel this is probably what other people do. I've heard it can be used to manage transactions, jndi lookups etc and they sound useful.

With this in mind I thought it also might start to solve my issue of lazy loading when retrieving domain objects over RMI.

I was wondering if anyone can give me some guidance as to whether I'm right in thinking this is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

The decision of using Tomcat (which from my point of view is more a lightweight container) versus a heavy one (JBoss AS, Glassfish, ...) depends mainly on what you need to do.

All containers share some basic stuff (e.g. database pooling, jmx, ..) but at a certain point (e.g. you need a heavy clustered solution with all automatic failover) the more complex containers provided more out of the box for such requierements. Of course you could also build such solutions with a lightweight solution but it is probably easier with a J2EE container.

On the other hand side POJOs are fare more easier to handle than EJBs and as long as you don't have any big and heavy requirements I would stick with Spring. Using only a small percentage of a J2EE container and build an application in it makes it not really a point to use.

Transaction handling in Spring and in J2EE is mostly the same (both ways can be done by using e.g. declarative approach (annotations)).

If you never run your application on a container I would start with the simpler one (Tomcat) and then approach the bigger ones if required as it makes your life probably easier. And as long as you hadn't any special requirements which you weren't be able to solve, I don't see any reason to start immediately with JBoss or Glassfish and rewrite your application to be J2EE conform.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of the blind leading the blind, but I think you are correct.  The app server is the packaging that holds all your little projects and binds them--it controls their lifecycle and other things you may not want to deal with manually like deployment, caching and redundancy.

Although I've coded to them for years inside various enterprise, It took me a while to figure out what they mean by "Container", something to contain little arbitrary independent pieces of code.

Better answers are probably already posted--Just wanted to let you know that you weren't alone :)